# Cannot open database by requested login

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc, flask-restful

[Error given on entering the url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F59KI.png)

```
import pyodbc


class MetaSingleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(
                MetaSingleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]


class Database(metaclass=MetaSingleton):
    connection = None

    def connect(self):
        if self.connection is None:
            self.connection = pyodbc.connect(
                'DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=LAPTOP-V5I3M0RK\SQLEXPRESS;Database=stock;UID=ABC_login;PWD=abc;Trusted_connection=yes;')

            # self.connection.autocommit = False
            self.cursorobj = self.connection.cursor()
        return self.cursorobj
```

This is the code I have been using to connect to my database I believe there is problem in the connection string after a lot of trial and error unable to figure out the problem.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: In your connection details, you provide a username, password *and* state you want to use a trusted connection; that doesn't make sense. You either pass the credentials and use SQL Authentication or use a trusted connection and the already authenticated Windows User's credentials the application is running under is used automatically.

Comment: _I believe there is problem in the connection string_ Why do you believe this, if (as you imply) this have been working some time? Rather it seems there might be some problem with the database. Use SSMS to access the server instance to determine the state of the database. Maybe it is offline?

Comment: Further to comment from @Larnu - `Trusted_Connection=yes` takes precedence over `UID` and `PWD` so your connection is using your Windows identity and not using `UID=ABC_login`